# how to use CupertinoPageRoute and named routes in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to use a CupertinoPageRoute instead of the Navigator.pushNamed 
with a routes array in MaterialApp. 
Navigator.pushNamed(context, p01.routeName); works fine.  But I want to accomplish two items.

1. I want the navigation to be Cupertino Style in Android.  Right To left, instead of Bottom to Top.
2. Navigation will go very deep, and I want to include a return button...  like this. Navigator.popUntil(context,
   ModalRoute.withName('/')); where I can return to specific locations
   in the navigation Stack.

HOW can I use routes, namedRoutes
and 
CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => p02.routeName);

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'p01.dart';
import 'p02.dart';
import 'p03.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      initialRoute: '/',
//      routes: {
//        '/p01' : (context) => p01(),
//        '/p02' : (context) => p02(),
//        '/p03' : (context) => p03(),
//      },
//***** .  this is what I am trying to use for routes.
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        p01.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new p01(title: "p01"),
        p02.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new p02(title: "p02"),
        p03.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new p03(title: "p03"),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text(" cup P01"),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("p01 was pressed");
                  //Navigator.pushNamed(context, p01.routeName);
//                  CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => AA02Disclaimer()),
                  //CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => p02());
//                  CupertinoPageRoute(  p02.routeName );

                  // p02.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new p02(title: "p02"),
//**** . this is the code I am trying to make work...
                  CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => p02.routeName);

                },
              ),
            ),
```

=======
This is code to return to the root.

```
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("/"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("/ was pressed");
//                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, p03.routeName);
                    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: you can add custom transition to app or you can use fluro package

Comment: Instead of using MaterialApp use CupertinoApp ..

Answer (score 41):

**TL;DR:** Use `onGenerate` of `MaterialApp` / `CupertinoApp` to use custom routes. For example `CupertinoPageRoute`. If you are already using the Cupertino-Style consider using `CupertinoApp`, which automatically uses the `CupertinoPageRoute`.

I've split this answer in two solutions, one with the default `MaterialApp`and one with the `CupertinoApp`(using Cupertino-Style):

---

**Keeping your style (MaterialApp):**

If you want to keep the [MaterialApp](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) as your root widget you'll have to replace the `routes` attribute of your `MaterialApp` with an `onGenerate` implementation:

*Original:*

```
routes: {
  '/': (_) => HomePage(),
  'deeper': (_) => DeeperPage(),
}
```

*Changed with `onGenerate`:*

```
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      return CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => HomePage(), settings: settings);
    case 'deeper':
      return CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => DeeperPage(), settings: settings);
  }
}
```

Now `onGenerate` handles the routing manually and uses for each route an [CupertinoPageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html). This replaces the complete `routes: {...}` structure.

*Quick standalone example:*

[image: MaterialApp Solution Example]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            return CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => HomePage(), settings: settings);
          case 'deeper':
            return CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => DeeperPage(), settings: settings);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Material!'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Take me deeper!'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'deeper'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeeperPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Material!'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Home :)'),
            onPressed: () =>
                Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/')),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Deeper!'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'deeper'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Cupterino Style (CupertinoApp):**

If you want to use the **Cupertino-Style** anyway, I would suggest to use the [CupertinoApp](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoApp-class.html) widget instead of the [MaterialApp](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget (like already suggested in a comment by @anmol.majhail).

Then the default chosen navigation will always use the [CupertinoPageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html).

Quick standalone example:

[image: CupertinoApp Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => HomePage(),
        'deeper': (_) => DeeperPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoButton(
          child: Text('Take me deeper!'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'deeper'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeeperPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          CupertinoButton(
            child: Text('Home :)'),
            onPressed: () =>
                Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/')),
          ),
          CupertinoButton(
            child: Text('Deeper!'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'deeper'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How should I send data between two screens?

Comment: @gsm You can use arguments property to pass object or just add parameter and constructor in second screen.