# Trying to add router with bottom navigation bar in CupertinoApp

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I am trying to add router with bottom navigation bar in CupertinoApp, but `Navigator.pushNamed(context,anotherPage)` is giving error

> Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/anotherPage", null) in the _CupertinoTabViewState.

but  `Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AnotherPage()));` is working
Sample code:

```
return CupertinoApp(
  localizationsDelegates: <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
    DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  theme: CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),  
 onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
  initialRoute: splashScreen,
); }}
```

//router class

```
    class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case homeRoute:
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => CupertinoHomePage()); 
      case productDetails:
        final ProductDetails args = settings.arguments;
        return CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                ProductDetails(args.productsPojo, args.userId));
      case anotherPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AnotherPage());   
        case splashScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SplashScreen());    
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => UndefinedView(name: settings.name));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the bottom nav bar is from google codelabs

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663793/how-to-use-cupertinopageroute-and-named-routes-in-flutter so have a look if you can find the answer there. Are the variables you use in the switch cases strings that match what you pass to pushNamed? Got no experience with CupertinoApp so it might be correct, but why are some routes CupertinoPageRoute and some MaterialPageRoute?

Comment: Sir, variables are never a problem. I have a constant class which stores all variables. In the past I was using metarialApp and that is working fine with routes. Now when I switch on, the CupertinoApp issue begins. And i also tried that solution but it also not working with Cupertino tab bar

Comment: i think the issue is with BottomNavigationBar of CupertinoTabBar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with this for some time.
CupertinoTabView has a 'routes' property. Put your app routes here

```
return CupertinoTabView(
      routes: appRoutes,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoPageScaffold(
          navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text(
              titles[currentRoute]
            ),
            trailing: FlatButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,),
              onPressed: openSearch,
            ),
          ),
          child: Material(
            child: Center(
              child: routes[currentRoute],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

appRoutes:

```
final appRoutes = {
  '/exampleRoute': (context) => ExampleRoute(),
  '/exampleRoute2': (context) => ExampleRoute2(),
}
```

You'll basically have to copy the routes you already declared in main.dart

Comment: yeah man it is working thanks for the help I will remember you lifetime

Comment: Searched a longtime for that solution, thank you!

Comment: thanks its helped, i have an issue is i want to get the current page name of CupertinoTabView but i get null , any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

@applejeewce said right.

You can also set **onGenerateRoutes** in place of routes in this scenario.