# How to change the transition animation of "Navigator.pushNamed" to cupertino style in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

As shown in the title, I want to change the transition animation of `Navigator.pushNamed` to cupertino style, but I don't know how to do it.

Help me, plz.

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55283902/4593315

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lines of code :

```
theme: ThemeData(
            pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
              builders: {
                TargetPlatform.android:
                    CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilderCustomBackGestureWidth(),
                TargetPlatform.iOS:
                    CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilderCustomBackGestureWidth(),
              },
            ),
          ),
```

All your transitions will be in cupertino style